# How do I disable highlighting math operators in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I do not know why but my VS 2013 is suddenly highlighting all math operators as seen below.

http://i.snag.gy/3T5l7.jpg

How can I disable this?

Comment: Having a custom color scheme might have something to do with it.  Tools + Options, Fonts and Colors, Display items = Operator

Comment: By the way, this is not a custom color scheme. It is one of the schemes called "Dark" that come pre-installed with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to reset settings. Refer to MSDN [/ResetSettings (devenv.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx)

```
Devenv.exe /ResetSettings
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. It also worked by changing color theme to a different one, then setting back to the current one.